# TypeError: _user2.default is not a constructor JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and ran into an issue. Basically what I am trying to do is create a new .js which only contains variables lets called the file **users.js**

```
var newuser = {
firstname:'Tony',
lastname: 'franklyn',
email:    `franky@gmail.com`,
password: 'Franklin123',
};

var User = {
email:    `checker@gmail.com`,
password: 'Checks',
 };

module.exports = {
newuser
};
```

Now in another file called **sign up**

```
  import news from './users.js';
  const newUser = new news();

 .typeText(Newuser.firstname)
```

I am trying to reference *newuser*
But after I run my code I get a *TypeError: _user2.default is not a constructor*

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: There are a couple weird things going on here.  (1) You're mixing features from various JS version (ie. `module.exports` & `import ...`) While this is technically okay, you might as well choose a path and stick with it.  If you're able to use the latest JS features, use `export default ...` instead. (2) You can't new up an object that is already instantiated.  You're exporting the already instantiated `var newUser = { ... }`.  Since this is true, you can simply use the object as imported.  No need to call `new news()`.

Comment: There is a very brief example here that might help you out: https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `new` operator on an object literal because the object literal is an object and not a class.

You need to structure your code as follows:

```
// user.js
function User() {
    return {
        firstname: 'Tony',
        lastname: 'franklyn',
        email: `franky@gmail.com`,
        password: 'Franklin123'
    }
}


let user = new User();
```

You may also use the `class` keyword if you are using ES6.

Comment: How to initiate User (let user = new User()) from different file? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using "new" on a JSON Object, when new should be used on a Class to create an instance.

you would use your code like this:
    import news from './users.js';
    news. newuser